# How can I display a full designer file in c#?

Tags: c#, file

So I just got a C# program from someone that compiles and gives me a 
fully functional application. However, when I want to see the .cs{Design] file it gives me the following error:

.ErrorStyle { font-family: tahoma; font-size: 11 pt; 
....

How can I convert this to an actual Design file? I am working on Visual Studio C#. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a CSS error. Do you have a screenshot of the error or screen that is incorrect?

Comment: All I am getting is:
<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title></title><style>.ErrorStyle { font-family: tahoma; font-size: 11 pt; text-align: left}.DetailsStyle { font-family: tahoma; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left;text-indent: 0; word-spacing: 0; line-height: 100%; float: left; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0}.StackStyleVisible { font-family: tahoma; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; margin-left: 20; text-indent: 0}.StackStyleHidden { display:none; font-family: tahoma; font-size: .....

Comment: A screen shot would definitely help in your issue. Either something in the project is broken and you're getting a pretty strange error message in code editor or this is the trace to some HTML type error. Where is the error displayed and in what context?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an error is being generated and all your seeing is the HTML version of the error. You need to get all the html throw it in a text file and view it as a html doc. Then you can see what the real error is.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply rebuild your solution, make sure the references are good then it should work fine.